# Convert Laravel query results from array of objects to array of indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this code

```
$datas = DB::table('uni_staff')
->join('department', 'uni_staff.department_id', 'department.id')
->join('uni_staff_type', 'uni_staff.type_id', 'uni_staff_type.id')
->select('uni_staff.*', 'department.dep_name as departmentName' , 'uni_staff_type.user_type as 
  typeName')
->where('uni_staff.id', $id)
->select('uni_staff.*')
->get();
```

I want to put every column value of a row to an indexed array, or print the result by column index like or something else `$datas[0]` not column names like `$datas->id`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the intended outcome and usage is?

Comment: @MhluziBhaka
this is my result of query :
{"id":3,"first_name":"pepe","middle_name":"ahmad","last_name":"ali","full_name":"pep shan  kj","pho_number":"ml;k","user_code":"ljl;j","type_id":1,"department_id":2,"internet1":"5654","internet2":"545","printer_code":546,"status":"544","date":"2020-11-18","note":"dsds","add_by":"dsd","departmentName":"Design","typeName":"Employee"} 

I want to put all column values to an array 
then use loop to print the array

Answer (score 1):

Without having to change any configuration you could use the Collection to map those objects to arrays and then call `array_values` on them:

```
$datas->map(fn ($row) => array_values((array) $row));
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using toArray?

```
$datas=DB::table('uni_staff')
->join('department','uni_staff.department_id','department.id')
->join('uni_staff_type','uni_staff.type_id','uni_staff_type.id')
->select('uni_staff.*','department.dep_name as departmentName' , 
'uni_staff_type.user_type as typeName')
->where('uni_staff.id',$id)
->select('uni_staff.*')
->get()
->toArray();
```

Comment: they would end up with an array of stdClass objects

Comment: Error message : " Cannot use object of type stdClass as array "